# Characterization of tail sigma algebra (and its complement)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am not able to extract the concept of a tail $\sigma$-algebra from its definition. So, given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and sub-$\sigma$-algebrae $\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2,\dots$ (e.g. $\mathcal{A}_j:=\sigma(X_j)$ for r.v. $X_1,X_2,\dots$ on $\Omega$) I call $$\mathcal{C}_\infty:=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty\sigma\left(\bigcup_{k=j}^\infty \mathcal{A}_k\right)$$ the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

So how would I extract from this defintion the property that allows people  say "this event is not part of $\mathcal{C}_\infty$ because it depends on $X_1$" as I often read?

There must be some assumptions for this statement to hold, e.g. $(X_j=X_1,\,j\in\mathbb{N})$ would disallow the statement (right?); I feel the $\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2,\dots$ must somehow "separate" the space?

Can someone give me a criterion with proof that allows me talk conceptually about tail $\sigma$-algebrae? Thank you very much. (I don't have trouble to see why e.g. $\limsup$'s are in the tail $\sigma$-algebra, I rather have trouble with giving negative answers)

Comment: You can extract it from this definition if the $X_n$ are independent. I think that concept tail sigma algebra is mostly looked at in a context of independent random variables.

Comment: @drhab I don't see how independency takes effect in this set-theoretic definition? Any hint? Can we talk about the tail $\sigma$-algebra without a probability measure? Thanks!

Comment: The tail $\sigma$-algebra makes sense for in general, and does not require a probability measure.  It does come up most often in connection with independent random variables because you have the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one result that captures the intuition of the tail algebra, at least for me.

Define two sequences $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots)$ to be tail equivalent if there exists an index $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $x_n = y_n$.  Then for any measurable set $S$ in the tail algebra, $x \in S$ if and only if $y \in S$.  So from the point of view of probability, $x$ and $y$ are indistinguishable.

This follows from this elementary result.  Let $Y$ be a probability space.  Consider the function $\pi: X \times Y \to Y$, $\pi( (x, y) ) = y$, and give $X \times Y$ the measure $\sigma(\pi)$.  Then for a measurable set $S$, $(x, y) \in S$ iff $(x', y) \in S$.  (This in turn follows from the definition of $\sigma(\pi)$.)

Comment: This looks promising, but I am not yet sure about the formalia. Do you mean  $x\in\Omega$ or $x\in\Omega^{\mathbb{N}}$ and how do you need the $X_j$ to relate to the $x_j$? Thanks!

Comment: $x_i \in \Sigma$, so $x \in \Sigma^\mathbb{N}$.  Imagine you draw $X_i$ for all $i$ -- this is the same as drawing an infinite random sequence.  Then the tail algebra can't tell two random sequences apart if they they both have the same tail.

Answer (score 1):

How about this as a simple heuristic, suppose there exists some $B\in \mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathbb{R})$ (the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the reals) such that $(X_{1}\in B)\setminus\left\{\bigcup_{k=2}^\infty (X_k \in B)\right\} \ne \emptyset$, so that there is some distinction between $X_1$ and what follows (they are certainly not identically the same as in your comment above, nor for that matter is each $X_j$ contained in its successor for example), then certainly: $$\sigma(X_1)\setminus(\bigcap_{j=2}^\infty\sigma(X_j))\ne\emptyset$$ Since there will definitely be events depending purely on $X_1$ and not on any of its successors. So in full generality then, $unless$ we have special conditions on the $X_j$ (eg inclusion in successors), we must have that the tail $\sigma$-algebra is $strictly$ smaller than $\sigma(X_1)$. Does that get to what you are asking or is it too simplistic? (And agreed we don't need a measure to define this). Cheers

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $(X_1\in A)$ for $A\in\mathcal{A}$, but starting from your second equation I think your argument could be helpful in some cases! Will keep it in mind, thanks!

Comment: Sorry need to edit bad notation will clarify! $(X_1 \in A)$ is shorthand for $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$ -But will edit gimme a sec!

Comment: No thats alright, I got you, but I wanted the $X_j$ to be defined on $\Omega$, that is $\omega\in A$ would make sense with my names! So you just wanted $A$ to be some measurable subset of the range, or not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion have clarified now should have been talking about a Borel set for example as the "$A$" hope makes more sense now!